# How to prove $\ B \cap A^c = B\iff\ A\cap\ B^c =A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm not sure if what i did is correct in order to prove this: $\ B \cap A^c = B\iff\ A\cap\ B^c =A$

What i tried:

$\ B \cap A^c = B\rightarrow\ A\cup\ B^c =A$

$\ B \cap A^c=B \ $ then

$A^c = B \ (\ idempotent  \ B\ \cap\ B = B) \ $or

$A^c = U   \ (\ B\cap\ U =B) $

$\Rightarrow \ A=B^c \ or \ A= \emptyset $

$ \Rightarrow  \ A\ \cap\ A = A \ \Rightarrow  A\ \cap\ B^c = A  $

And for $\ B \cap A^c = B\leftarrow A\cup\ B^c =A$ is analog

Thanks for the help

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match with the one in the body.

Comment: Line 2 to 4 are not correct. A counterexample is $U = \mathbb{N}, A = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1, 2, 3\}, B = \{1\}$. Then $A^{c} = {1, 2, 3}$ but not $U$ or $B$. It only gives you $B \subset A^c$ as information.

Comment: $B\cap A^c=B$ is equivalent to saying that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, i.e., $A\cap B=\emptyset$, so the conclusion immediately follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B \cap A^c = B$ implies $B \subseteq A^c$. (Here you only consider two sub-cases: $A^c=B$ or $A^c=U$ where $U$ is the whole space?)

Then we have $A \subseteq B^c$, from which you can get $A \cap B^c=A$.

---

An alternate proof is to show that both sides are equivalent to $A \cap B = \varnothing$ (that is, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct; for instance, if $U=\{1,2,3\}$, $A=\{1\}$, and $B=\{2\}$, then $B\cap A^c=B$, but $A^c\neq B$ and  $A^c\neq U$. You may want to use that $A^c\cap B=B$ if and only if $B\subset A^c$

Answer (score 0):

There is a type in the title; if not then it is false.
$$S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\B=\{1,2\}\text { and }B^c=\{3,4,5\}\\A=\{4,5\}\text{ and }A^c=\{1,2,3\}$$ In this case you have $\ B \cap A^c = B$ but not $A\cup B^c\ne A $ and  you rather have  $A\cap B^c=A$.

You must put $A\cap B^c=A$ instead of $A\cup B^c= A $

Answer (score 0):

$B \cap A^c = B$ iff $B \subseteq A^c$ iff $A \subseteq B^c$ iff $A \cap B^c = A.$